# A command looks like it's invisible to the whole program , PDO

Tags: php, pdo

This cmd should make a background of a row purple if it's an event going in that date , but acts like it's invisible with no error report

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM eventcalendar where eventDate ='.$dateToCompare.'');
            $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($row_count !=0) {
            echo "class='event'";
        }
    ("class='event'"; is the background changing cmd)
```

It is my first time i post on this site and try to reach someone to help me in this kind of situation , it might look a little messy . I'll say sorry for making this mess question. Appreciate your atention , ty.

For example , the day 19 and 20 should be purple ;
[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJYPl.png)
The db prg here(it has some comments of other tryes):

```
<?php
 $hostname = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password ="";
 $dbname = "calendar";
 $error = "Cannot connect to database, Please try again later...";
//mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ($error);
 //mysqli_select_db($dbname) or die ($error);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '');
// $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password);

//if ($conn->connect_error) {
   // die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
//} 
?>
<html>
<head>
 <script>
   function goLastMonth(month, year){ 
     if (month == 1) { 
       --year;
       month = 13;

     }
     --month
     var monthstring = ""+month+"";
     var monthlength = monthstring.length;
     if(monthlength <= 1){
      monthstring = "0"+monthstring;
     document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year;
     }

   function goNextMonth(month, year){ 
     if (month == 12){ 
       ++year;
       month = 0;

     }
      ++month
     var monthstring = ""+month+"";
     var monthlength = monthstring.length;
     if(monthlength < 1){
         monthstring = "0"+monthstring;
     document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year;
     }
 </script>
<style>
    .today {
        background-color : #00ff00;
    }
    .event {
        background-color : #9400D3;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//check if day has passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['day'])){
 $day = $_GET['day'];
}else{
$day = date ("j");
}

if (isset ($_GET['month'])){
 $month = $_GET['month'];
}else{
$month = date ("n");
}
if (isset ($_GET['year'])){
 $year = $_GET['year'];
}else{
$year = date ("Y");
}
//calender valiable
$currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
//get current month name
$monthName = date ("F", $currentTimeStamp);
//Determine how many day there are in this month
$numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp);
//variable to count cell in the loop later
$counter = 0;
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['add'])){
    $title = $_POST['txttitle'];
    $detail = $_POST['txtdetail'];
    $eventdate = $month."/".$day."/".$year;
    $dildau = date("Y/m/d");
    //$sql = "INSERT INTO eventcalendar (title, detail, eventDate)
    //VALUES ('$title','$detail','date()')";
    $str = $db->query("INSERT INTO eventcalendar (title, detail, eventDate, DataAdaugarii)
    VALUES ('$title','$detail','$eventdate','$dildau')");
    $resultinsert = $str;
    if($resultinsert) {
        echo "Event was succesfully Added...";
    }else{
        echo "Event Failed to be Added...";
}}
?>
<table border='1'>
 <tr>
  <td><input style='width:50px;' type='button' value='<' name='previousbutton' onClick="goLastMonth (<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"></td>
        <td colspan='5'><?php echo $monthName.", ".$year; ?></td>
        <td><input style='width:50px;' type='button' value='>' name='nextbutton' onClick="goNextMonth (<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"></td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width='50px'>Sun</td>
        <td width='50px'>Mon</td>
        <td width='50px'>Tue</td>
        <td width='50px'>Wed</td>
        <td width='50px'>Thu</td>
        <td width='50px'>Fri</td>
        <td width='50px'>Sat</td>
 </tr>
    <?php
  echo "<tr>";

  for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++) { 
    $timeStamp = strtotime ("$year-$month-$i");
    if($i == 1){ 
      $firstDay = date ("w", $timeStamp);
      for ($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++){ 
      //blank space
      echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
      }
    } 

    if($counter % 7 == 0 ){ 
         echo "<tr></tr>";

      }
      $monthstring = $month;
      $monthlength = strlen($monthstring);
      $daystring = $i;
      $daylength = strlen($daystring);
      if($monthlength <= 1){
          $monthstring = "0".$monthstring;
      }
      if($daylength <= 1) {
          $daystring = "0".$daystring;
      }
        $todaysDate = date("m/d/Y");
        $dateToCompare = $monthstring.'/'.$daystring.'/'.$year; 
        echo "<td align='center' ";
        if ($todaysDate == $dateToCompare){
         echo "class='today'";
        }else{
            //$sqlCount = "select * from eventcalendar where eventDate ='".$dateToCompare."'";
            //$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCount); $noOfEvent = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            //$noOfEvent = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sqlCount));
            //public PDOStatement PDO::query ('SELECT * FROM eventcalendar where eventDate=$dateToCompare');
            $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM eventcalendar where eventDate ='.$dateToCompare.'');
            $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($row_count !=0) {
            echo "class='event'";
        }
        }
        echo "><a href ='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$daystring."&year=".$year."&v=true'>".$i."</a></td>";

  }

  echo "</tr>";

 ?>
</table>
  <?php 
  if(isset($_GET['v'])){
      echo "<a href ='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$month."&day=".$day."&year=".$year."&v=true&f=true'>Add Event</a>";
      if(isset($_GET['f'])){
      include("calendareventadd.php");  
  }
  //$sqlEvent = "select * from eventcalendar where eventDate='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'";
  //$resultEvents = mysql_query($sqlEvent);
  $str = $db->query("select * from eventcalendar where eventDate='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'");
  ///$resultEvents = $st = $db->query("select * from eventcalendar where eventDate='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'");
  $allah = $str->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   echo "<hr>";
  //while($events = mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
      if($events = $allah){
      echo "Evenimente in ziua selectata: "."<br>";
      echo "Title: ".$events['title']."<br>";
      echo "Detail: ".$events['detail']."<br>";
  }
  } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, first off, your `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` doesn't output anything, you have no `echo` in front of them. Dunno if that is the cause of the problems (probably not), but should be fixed. You can use `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`, btw.

Comment: You are SQL injection yourself. Run your query using prepared statement and it will be ok

Comment: I don t think that s the problem , has no relation with the structure i m asking.